# How may I establish a render farm over WAN?

Tags: rendering, network

I'm using the blender network render plugin in the official plugin list. I have a few computers throughout the internet(WAN) that I am able to render on. Assuming I can get network connectivity(forwarding ports and other considerations), what kind of bandwidth requirements are there?

I have mainly procedural materials of 40 or so nodes, and only one scene. The .blend file is approximately 9MB. Will this file need to be sent once for each render slave, and each frame sent back? Or will more communication be needed that is not negligible? (I'm not using baked or cached simulations)

I'm assuming bursts of high activity when sending and receiving frames. Would this be true in practice? Or would other bandwidth considerations need to be taken?

Comment: To closevoters: This discusses a feature that as per http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/68, number 5, (being an officially-included plugin) is on-topic as far as I know.

Comment: I concur. The Network Render plugin is included with Blender and thus official. We need more info on it IMHO.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Can you clarify what are your concerns?

Comment: voted down, this depends a lot on your configuration, and the kinds of scenes you have - blend files can be 200k or 400mb. Best ask specific question relating to your project. or better, try it out and then come back with a more detailed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bandwidth requirement are highly dependent on your scene. With the official Network Renderer, you will need enough bandwidth to copy the scene file over to the each of the slaves (once), and then get the rendered images back (every frame). The communication overhead is negligible.